# Android OpenCV seamlessClone how to use for big bitmap?

Tags: opencv, android

I use seamlessClone to process a big bitmap,but when `seamlessClone` execute,it will use very large memory and cause app crash.I test 1200*1200,it work successfully,but when bitmap is over 2000*2000,it will trigger out of memory flashback,profiler show when `seamlessClone` execute,memory usage quickly exceeded 1G.When use 1200*1200,memory usage is from 240M to about 400MB.

Before `seamlessClone`,breakpoints is `val matBlend = Mat.zeros(matDst.size(), matDst.type())`
[image]
When `seamlessClone`,from 0.3G to 1G.
[image]
I hope users can save the original size of the picture after use,so maybe bitmap option is not available.

```
fun cvCompound(originBm: Bitmap, dstBm: Bitmap, maskBm: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    var matSrc = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(originBm, matSrc)
    originBm.recycle()
    cvtColor(matSrc, matSrc, COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 3)
    var matDst = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(dstBm, matDst)
    dstBm.recycle()
    cvtColor(matDst, matDst, COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 3)
    var matMask = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(maskBm, matMask)
    cvtColor(matMask, matMask, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 1)
    var r = boundingRect(matMask)
    var point = Point((r.tl().x + r.br().x) / 2, (r.tl().y + r.br().y) / 2)
    val matBlend = Mat.zeros(matDst.size(), matDst.type())
    seamlessClone(matSrc, matDst, matMask, point, matBlend, MIXED_CLONE)
    matSrc.release()
    matDst.release()
    matMask.release()
    var bitmap = createBitmap(matBlend.cols(), matBlend.rows(), ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(matBlend, bitmap)
    matBlend.release()
    return bitmap
}
```

For large images, how should I use seamlessClone? Can you give me any Suggestions, thanks.

Comment: The function does most of the work using 32bit floats, and it uses a number of temporary `Mat`s (of dimensions corresponding to the bounding box of the mask)... I've counted at least 6x 32FC3, 10x 32FC1 as well as some 8UC3 and 8UC1.

Comment: I came up with a temporary way to cut the large image into several pieces and merge them separately, but meet an even stranger problem. It took about 500ms on the simulator, but it was 10 times slower on armv7 and armv8 phones